# How to have SEO URLs incorporate more than just the name of the product?

Tags: websphere-commerce, wcs

When you generate SEO URLs according to the IBM tutorials, you end up with URLs that look like this for a book called "Death wears a green hat":

> http://www.shop.com/mystore/shop/thrillers/death-wears-a-green-hat

How do I configure it to generate URLs that incorporate more than just the title, eg. the author name:

> http://www.shop.com/mystore/shop/thrillers/john-doe-death-wears-a-green-hat

I can hack the seourlkeywordgen batch file, but what about delta updates to new products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an XML file that controls the default SEO generation.  See http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.commerce.seositemap.doc/concepts/csdSEOURLconstruction.htm

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for: I know where to find the documentation, but was looking for a concrete example that incorporates more than one attribute of the product in the SEO UL. Still a +1 for helping out!

Comment: I have decided to accept your answer, even though it's not exactly what I was looking for. In most cases it would be the right answer :) In our case, the system was so heavily customized that we had to go with another solution.